# Determine type of empty wildcard collection (e.g. List<? extends Number>)

Tags: java, generics, collections

I have a `Collection` of elements. When the `Collection` is populated, it's easy to get the first element and work out what type it is. But when the `Collection` is empty, I can't work out how do to it.

Example below:

```
public static void main(final String args[])
{
    typer(Collections.singletonList(Integer.valueOf(0)));
    typer(Collections.singletonList(Double.valueOf(0)));

    typer(Collections.<Integer> emptyList());
}

private static void typer(final List<? extends Number> list)
{
    if (list.isEmpty())
    {
        System.out.println(list.getClass());
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println(list.get(0).getClass());
    }
}
```

The output produced is:

```
class java.lang.Integer
class java.lang.Double
class java.util.Collections$EmptyList
```

Comment: "When the Collection is populated, it's easy to get the first element and work out what type it is" No it isn't. I could create `class X extends Number` and `class Y extends X` and put an instance of `Y` into a `List<X>`. By looking at the first element you'd infer to type of the `List` to be `List<Y>` even though it isn't.

Comment: Also, you can't. If your design relies on you knowing the type of the elements then I'd say it's 99% certain that your design is wrong.

Comment: @Michael I appreciate that I can't ensure it's exclusive an X, and not just something that extends X, but that distinction works for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. [Actual type parameters are erased during run time.](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/erasure.html) An empty `List<String>` is exactly the same as a `List<Integer>`.

Answer (score 0):

I think that it's helpful not to think of `List<Integer>` as being "a list of `Integer`s".

Instead, think of it as simply a `List`; but you have also given a hint to the compiler to stop you putting in anything other than an `Integer` (or a subclass, or null), and to stop you taking anything out other than an `Integer` (or null).

If you think of it like this, you get away from the idea that "you can determine the type of the `List`". *It's just a `List`*. The stuff about `Integer` only exists at compile time.

Even if the list is non-empty, you can't really tell what the "type" of the list is: a non-empty `List<Object>` can contain only instances of `Integer`. So, you can only ever determine a lower bound on the type.